# Uploading image to server(mysql database) using android and php

Tags: php, android, mysql, image-uploading

In my code i am having two images and two edittext fields to send to the database using php file.Here in my code i am able to insert 2 images along with the edittext fileds without any problem.
Now whats my problem is when a user enters two  edittext fields and selects only one image to insert, it is throwing `NullPointerException`.Here with this code i have to select 2 images mandatorily..how can i make that one optional.?I mean user can select one/two image based on his requirement.But if i select only one image,it is throwing null pointer exception.please help me..!!

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonUpload;
    private Button buttonChoose;
    private Button buttonChoose1;

    private EditText edithouse;
    private EditText editbuild;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ImageView imageView1;

    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE1 = "image1";
    public static final String KEY_TEXT = "house";
    public static final String KEY_TEXT1 = "build";
    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://oursite/PhotoUploadWithText/upload.php";

    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST1 = 2;

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Bitmap bitmap1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose);
        buttonChoose1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose1);

        edithouse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.houseno);
        editbuild = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.buildno);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViews);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViews1);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonChoose1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
          private void showFileChooser1() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST1);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               // imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    public String getStringImage1(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }


    public void uploadImage(){
        final String house = edithouse.getText().toString().trim();
        final String build = editbuild.getText().toString().trim();
        final String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
        final String image1 = getStringImage1(bitmap1);
        class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Please wait...","uploading",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();
                param.put(KEY_TEXT,house);
                param.put(KEY_TEXT1,build);
                param.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);
                param.put(KEY_IMAGE1,image1);
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, param);
                return result;
            }
        }
        UploadImage u = new UploadImage();
        u.execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonChoose){
            showFileChooser();
        }
        if(v == buttonUpload){
            uploadImage();
        }
        if(v == buttonChoose1){
            showFileChooser1();
        }
    }
}
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $image = $_POST['image'];
        $house = $_POST['house '];
        $image1 = $_POST['image1'];
        $build = $_POST['build '];

        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        $sql ="SELECT id FROM uploads ORDER BY id ASC";

        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

         $id = uniqid();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                $id = $row['id'];
        }

        $path = "uploads/".uniqid().".png";
                $path1 = "uploads/".uniqid().".png";

        $actualpath  = "$path";
        $actualpath1  = "$path1";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO uploads (image,house,image1,build) VALUES ('$actualpath','$house','$actualpath1','$build')";

        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
                        file_put_contents($path1,base64_decode($image1));
            echo "Successfully Uploaded";
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
?>
```

Here is the error..
**Logcat**

```
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.getStringImage1(MainActivity.java:118)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.uploadImage(MainActivity.java:129)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:168)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-17 17:28:33.261: E/AndroidRuntime(14710):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call  `public void uploadImage()`
check

```
String image = null;
String image1 = null;
    if(bitmap != null)
        image = getStringImage(bitmap);
    if(bitmap1 != null)
        image1 = getStringImage1(bitmap1);
```

also Check

```
if(image != null)
    param.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);
if(image1 != null)
    param.put(KEY_IMAGE1,image1);

String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, param);
```

and then also in php check if

> KEY_IMAGE

and

> KEY_IMAGE1

exists then do whatever you want to do, otherwise php will throw an error for undefined index.

Comment: In `doInBackground(Void... params)` method..if i use `param.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);` ..it is asking to change modifier of image and image1 to final..But in `uploadImage()` method if i declare as final.inside if statement it is throwing error..

Comment: make image and image1 global varibales

Comment: Glad i could help, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting one image and uploading two in uploadimage method...

just use below code it will work for you..

```
String image1 = "";
     if(bitmap1!=null)
     image1 = getStringImage1(bitmap1);
```

Comment: In `doInBackground(Void... params)` method..if i use `param.put(KEY_IMAGE1,image1);` ..it is asking to change modifier of image1 to final..But in `uploadImage()` method if i declare as final.inside if statement it is throwing errors for image1